# How can I execute an action after loop has ended?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a loop that modifies an array and after completing the whole loop the idea is to execute some code with the modified array, but when I try to do it the code after the loop is executed before the array has been modified.

I wonder if there is a way to do it, like executing the loop synchronously.

I've tried using *callbacks* and *async/await* calls, but it didn't work for me.

```
for (m in muns) {
  model.findAll({
    ...
  })
  .then((con) => {
    if (con.length != 0) {
      for (c of con) {
        if (!(muns.includes(c.origen))) {
          muns.push(c.origen)
        }
        if (!(muns.includes(c.destino))) {
          muns.push(c.destino)
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
console.log(muns)
```

I Expected to get `muns` array modified, but instead it hasn't change.

Comment: The `findAll` is asynchronous, so the `console.log` executes before it finishes. You need to process the result in the `then` function.

Comment: This is a problem due to how `Promise`s work. You can't really get values from outside your `Promise` because it is running asynchronously, so what I can suggest is that you move `console.log(muns)` just after the for-loop, or `return muns` from inside the `then` callback and use `then` again to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since `findAll` is asynchronous, the code after it will execute right away, without waiting for it to be finished.
To get around this, you can just move the `console.log` to inside the `then` callback:

```
model.findAll({ ....}).then((con) => {
    if (con.length != 0) {
        for (c of con) {
            if (!(muns.includes(c.origen))) {
                muns.push(c.origen)
            }
            if (!(muns.includes(c.destino))) {
                muns.push(c.destino)
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(muns)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how asynchronism works.

```
  model.findAll({ // This is done FIRST
    ...
  })
  .then(() => { // This is done whenever it's done, so it will happen THIRD
    ... 
  });

  console.log(muns) // This is done SECOND
```

One way to deal with it :

```
  model.findAll({ // This is done FIRST
    ...
  })
  .then(nextFunction); // This is done whenever it's done, it will happen SECOND

  const nextFunction = () => console.log(muns) // This is done THIRD
```